# Extend to fragment or activity

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I trying to create a `navigation drawer` in my apps. I have 3 present options(View,Claims,Report) and of course the 3 activities are extend to `fragment`. In `View`, it has a `next` button which will go to another page(`UpdatePage1.java`). Does the page need to extend to `fragment` or just extend to `Activity`?

I extend the `UpdatePage1` to `fragment` and my app crashed.

**LogCat**

```
Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.project.project/com.example.project.project.UpdatePage1}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Why would this happen? I thought it never need to add fragments to manifest? Please help.

Comment: `UpdatePage1`need extend to `Activity` and then declared on `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Cannot fragment to fragment?

Comment: You can chose to either implement an `Activity` or `Fragment`, but you must understand that fragments are contained within activities. So you'll be swapping one fragment out with another if you want to page via that approach

Comment: yes, you can, but maybe Are you using `startActivity` to open `UpdatePage1`? to call `Fragment` from `Fragment` it's different  @Hoo

Comment: I using startActivity(Intent)

Comment: That's the problem, if `UpdatePage1` is not a `Activity` you can't use `StartActivity`, it's different.

Comment: Check my answer @Hoo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `Fragment` from another `Fragment`:

```
SecondFragment secFrag = new SecondFragment();
FragmentTransaction fragTransaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_layout,secFrag );
                    fragTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                    fragTransaction.commit();
```